# How coordinates points works in LinearGradient?

Tags: xamarin.android, gradient, linear-gradients

Can anyone please explain or describe how the coordinates points in the LinearGradient?

For example: I have my code in this way.

```
   var gradient = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 500, 500, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.Clamp);
   paint.SetShader(gradient);
   paint.Dither = true;
```

how it display in the rectangle while applying in the rectangle ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]
In Android, the coordinate system always is like what you can see above picture.

1) (0,0) is top left corner.

2) (maxX,0) is top right corner

3) (0,maxY) is bottom left corner

4) (maxX,maxY) is bottom right corner

The maxX or maxY is the screen's(or view's) max width or max height.

This `new LinearGradient(0, 0, 500, 500, colors, null, Shader.TileMode.Clamp)` method will be sure a `Gradient line` which you can see in above picture. And when you use `Canvas` to draw the rectangle with the paint, the colors will be rendered along this line.